# Serial input ok but output queue fails

Tags: serial-port, pyserial, virtual-serial-port

I'm using Python 2.7, pySerial under windows 7.

I have 8 devices, they are connected to my PC via Virtual COM port (Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge), I'm testing them With multiprocessing all 8 COM ports are open and each time i'm sending command to one unit only, there is no MultiThreading.

The problem is that after X time (it could be 10 minutes or 5 hours), the output Queue of the serial ports fails to send me responses. it's not a specific port each time it's a different port (it can be several ports)

It's importent to say, the device gets my command and do it. the fail is to get the response, The device i'm testing is OK for sure.
I am sniffing the port with Serial monitor, all the  commands send OK and the device makes them, only it doesn't respond.

Any idea's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be n number of reasons:

- Buffers might be full
- Com Port is not working or might be
- And finally the device is malfunctioning..

Check out these things might be it will help you.